# props is not sending data to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So, What i am doing, i am sending 2 arrays to another component as props and when i receive that props from the other component it is showing as undefined

> **Senddata.ts (Component which sends data to other component)**

```
import React from "react";
import DynamicTable from "./DynamicTable";
export interface mydata {
  columns?: [{ text: string; dataField: string }];
  data?: [];
}

const Datasender = () => {
  let columns = [
    { text: "Id", dataField: "id" },
    { text: "Name", dataField: "name" }
  ];

  let data = [
    { id: 1, name: "Manikanta", age: 20, Gender: "male", expandabale: true },
    { id: 2, name: "Varsha", age: 85, Gender: "female", expandabale: true },
    { id: 3, name: "Sai", age: 18, Gender: "male", expandabale: true },
    { id: 4, name: "John", age: 24, Gender: "female", expandabale: false }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((data) => 
        <DynamicTable data={data} col={columns} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Datasender;
```

> **DynamicTable.ts (Component which recieves data from  senddata component)**

```
import React from 'react'
 const DynamicTable =(props: any) =>
 {
     return(
         <div className="table-responsive">
             <table className="table">
              <thead>
                  <th scope="col"> #</th>
                  {props.col.map((col: { text: React.ReactNode }) =>{
                      return <th scope="col">{col.text}</th>
                  })}
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      
                      <td></td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
             </table>


         </div>
     )
 }
 export default DynamicTable
```

When i console log the props it is showing as undefined and there is a error with map as undefined too.
Any Modifications to code is to be done?

Comment: Can you please provide a codesandbox link?

Comment: just one note, why do you want to iterate through data and send each element to DynamicTable Component? you should pass all the data without iterate through them and inside the DynamicTable component you can iterate on them

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, try this approach:

1. Define an interface for ColumnProps and Data:

   ```
   interface Columns
   {
      text: string, 
      dataField: string,
   }

   interface ColumnProps {
      columns: Columns[];
   }

   interface Data
   {
       id: number, 
       name: string,
       age: number,
       Gender: string,
       expandabale: boolean
   }
   ```
2. Then define type for `DynamicTable` props:

   ```
   type DynamicTableProps = {
      data: Data,
      columns: ColumnProps 
   }
   ```
3. Finally, your `DynamicTable`:

   ```
   const DynamicTable = ({ data, columns}: DynamicTableProps) => {...}
   ```